# Testing with Karma Angular NgRX effects with applied timer

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-runner, ngrx

Having the following NgRX effect

```
loadData$: Observable<any> = createEffect((): Observable<Action> => {
        return this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(loadDataStarted),
            switchMap(() => {
                return timer(0, 10000).pipe(
                    switchMap(() => this.dataService.loadNewData().pipe(
           
                    )),
                );
            }),
        );
    });
```

after all the requirements are mocked try to test if dataService.loadNewData() is getting called, but the test will fail

```
beforeEach(() => {
     service.loadNewData.and.returnValue(of(data));
});

it('should call service', fakeAsync(() => {
    tick(10000)
    expect(service.loadNewData).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith();
}));
```

How do I mock correctly this case

Comment: https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/testing-an-ngrx-project#effects

Comment: @timdeschryver thanks for your feedback, the linked documentation seems to cover cases in jest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you perform the subscription to the effect outside of the actual test (the `it` block). This means the subscription lives *outside* of the `fakeAsync` timer and because of this, the `tick(..)` has no effect.

To solve this, make sure to setup everything inside your `fakeAsync` test block.

A general recommendation would be to use marble testing for this: https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/testing#marble-diagrams

**Edit:** A concrete solution is found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65857864/2544163